# Can't livestream with FFmpeg on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I am trying to livestream through RTMP on FFmpeg in Nginx. Doing `sudo ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i test.mp4  -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/stream` gives me `ioctl(VIDIOC_QUERYCAP): Inappropriate ioctl for device
test.mp4: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Am I even doing this right?

Comment: Remove `-f video4linux2`. It tells ffmpeg to capture video from camera instead of local media file